# Injecting an object into a HttpSessionAttributeListener via Guice?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, dependency-injection, guice

**Configuration**: Guice 1.0, Apache Tomcat 6.0

I am currently manually injecting objects configured in a Guice Module, into my servlet, using this method:

```
public void init( ServletConfig config ) throws ServletException
{
    super.init( config );
    ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext();
    Injector injector = (Injector) sc
        .getAttribute( Constants.Guice.INJECTOR_APP_CONTEXT_KEY );
    injector.injectMembers( this );
}
```

How can I do the same into a HttpSessionAttributeListener (since it doesn't have any lifecycle methods) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event Listener is all about life-cycle events. For example, `attributeAdded()` is called right after an attribute is added to a session, similar to init() for Servlet.

It probably makes more sense to inject object into HttpSession. In that case, you want do it in `HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated()`.

Comment: What is the difference between HttpSessionListener and HttpSessionAttributeListener ?

Comment: One listens to the event for the session and the other for a single attribute in the session.